# Is it possible to use Jenkins server to run custom tasks one by one?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

Is it possible to use Jenkins server to run custom tasks one by one?

By task I mean to execute an external groovy program which designed as an independent performance and integration test for specific deployment.

If it is possible then how to:

1. To define tasks in Jenkins and group them so they can start by starting a group.
2. To see an output of each task (output log).
3. If there is a specific outcome like "-1" then stop execution of the whole group.

And all this should start automatically after software has been built and deployed.

I feel there has to be a way to do it with Jenkins utilising its out-of-the-box functionality, just not sure how. Or I am wrong and we are looking at custom plugin as a solution?

Thanks a lot!

P.S. I am not asking for detailed answer, just a general direction would be Ok. Also Jenkins is not a requirement, it can be another similar CI server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this could work by a simple Jenkins task with `Execute shell` commands.

The `Console Output` for the jobs will contain the output from the processes that you run externally, and the exit status of the script can cause the task to be in failure (any non-zero exit code will do this by default).

On unix systems, `#!` beginning the first line will denote the script environment to use.

To chain this together with the other Jenkins steps, you can use `Build Triggers` for `Build after other projects are built` and use your deployment step as the starting off point.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but be careful. Normally Jenkins is used to run build jobs and to deploy software to a QA or staging server. It does not touch Production. But when you start doing this in Jenkins you increase the risk that someone will accidentally run a production job that should not have been run. So if you do decide to use Jenkins for this, set up an entirely separate instance of Jenkins that does nothing other than run these jobs. Then go to Manage Jenkins->Configure Global Security and set up login users. At the least, use "logged in users can do anything" but it would be better to set up "matrix-based security". Then run any jobs that you need by using an Execute Shell step. You can schedule jobs by using a Build Trigger, and you can connect jobs sequentially by setting up Build Other Projects in the post build section. If you want to do more complex job chaining, look into the Join Plugin.

Just keep this Jenkins entirely separate from the Jenkins which you use for CI.